# rearding regex (python)

Tags: python, regex

I have long strings. Like this

```
{{ name = name
    prodcuer =producer
    writer = writer 
    language = {{english}}
    country = USA 
}}
Here is text I Need This paragraph.;
```

I don't want text between `{{` `}}`. I tried with `regex` but not found any luck. Can anyone help me please?

Comment: If the `{{}}` can be nested to arbitrary depth, then this is not a finite-state/regexp problem.

Comment: show us tye regex you've tried

Comment: Please specify if You just want to extract last paragraph, or remove the text between `{{ }}` ? More examples would be helpful as well.

Comment: @Dejw I just need last paragraph

Comment: @DmitryBeransky Here is my code `re.search(r'(?ms).*?{{(.*?)}}', text)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here: http://rubular.com/r/CCW7sAUMrs is an example regex that matches whole text within `{{ }}`.

You can easily clean up Your string with it using `re.sub`.

**Note, that it will not work when You have text like `{{test}} paragraph {{test}}`, because it will match whole string.**

As larsmans said, it gets harder if You can nest braces. Then it is the job for some kind of [Pushdown automaton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pushdown_automaton).

**Edit:**

Here is the usage:

```
>>> text = """
... {{ name = name
...     prodcuer =producer
...     writer = writer 
...     language = {{english}}
...     country = USA 
... }}
... Here is text I Need This paragraph.;
... """
>>> import re
>>> exp = "\{\{.+\}\}"
>>> re.sub(exp, "", text, flags=re.S | re.I).strip()
'Here is text I Need This paragraph.;'
```

Comment: Is It correct? `text = re.search(r'\{\{.+\}\}',text)`

Answer (score 0):

This looks like some sort of template file.  Python has multiple templating engines available, and if you use one that will allow `{{` and `}}` to mark the replacement text, you could just use the template engine to replace that whole thing with the empty string.

You are probably already using some sort of templating engine since you have that text there.  Can you just use that engine to get rid of the `{{` `}}`?