# How do I avoid text between {{ }}

Tags: python, regex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [My regex is not working properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8029633/my-regex-is-not-working-properly)

Suppose I have long text. From following text I need only abstract part. How do I avoid text between `{{ }}`. Thanks
`

```
{{ Info extra text}}
{{Infobox film
| name           = Papori
| released       = 1986
| runtime        = 144 minutes
| country        = Assam, {{IND}}
| budget         = [[a]]
| followed by    = free
}}
Albert Einstein ( /'ælb?rt 'a?nsta?n/; German: ['alb?t 'a?n?ta?n] ( listen); 14 March 1879 – 18 April 1955)
 was a German-born theoretical physicist who developed the theory of general relativity, effecting a
 revolution in physics. For this achievement, Einstein is often regarded as the father of modern physics 
 and one of the most prolific intellects in human history.`
```

OUTPUT:

```
Albert Einstein ( /'ælb?rt 'a?nsta?n/; German: ['alb?t 'a?n?ta?n] ( listen); 14 March 1879 – 18 April 1955)
 was a German-born theoretical physicist who developed the theory of general relativity, effecting a
 revolution in physics. For this achievement, Einstein is often regarded as the father of modern physics 
 and one of the most prolific intellects in human history.
```

Comment: If you're *really* just asking how to get abstracts from Wikipedia articles, note that the fine folks at [DBpedia](http://dbpedia.org/page/Albert_Einstein) make Wikipedia articles available in a structured way (and also deal with the wiki markup).

Comment: @John Flatness Does DBpedia provide `API`?

Comment: duplicate of [My regex is not working properly](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8029633/my-regex-is-not-working-properly) and [regarding regex python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028729/rearding-regex-python)

Comment: This is your _third question_ about doing this exact same thing. If the previous answers aren't working for you _update the question_, don't just keep asking it over and over again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I did:

```
>>> text
"{{ Info extra text}}\n{{Infobox film\n| name           = Papori\n| released       = 1986\n| runtime        = 144 minutes\n| country        = Assam, {{IND}}\n| budget         = [[a]]\n| followed by    = free\n}}\nAlbert Einstein ( /'ælb?rt 'a?nsta?n/; German: ['alb?t 'a?n?ta?n] ( listen); 14 March 1879 – 18 April 1955)\n was a German-born theoretical physicist who developed the theory of general relativity, effecting a\n revolution in physics. For this achievement, Einstein is often regarded as the father of modern physics \n and one of the most prolific intellects in human history.`"
>>> re.sub(r"\{\{[\w\W\n\s]*\}\}", "", text)
"\nAlbert Einstein ( /'ælb?rt 'a?nsta?n/; German: ['alb?t 'a?n?ta?n] ( listen); 14 March 1879 – 18 April 1955)\n was a German-born theoretical physicist who developed the theory of general relativity, effecting a\n revolution in physics. For this achievement, Einstein is often regarded as the father of modern physics \n and one of the most prolific intellects in human history.`"
```

Edit: Bart's comment is correct.

Might consider this alternative:

```
>>> re.sub(r"\{\{[^\}]*\}\}", "", "{{a\n   oaheduh}} b {{c}} d")
' b  d'
```

Comment: That matches the first `{{` and then consumes everything up to the last `}}`. This might work for the (single) example the OP posted, but will also remove the `"b"` in `"{{a}} b {{c}}"`.

Comment: Also, you can remove `\n\s` from `[\w\W\n\s]`, those sets are already matched by `\W`.